# python handeling ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer in cpanel

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, cpanel

I have a flask project running on a cpanel host everything works fine expect than every 24 hours
i get this errors and if will end with more errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 760, in _write_bytes
    self._sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site- 
packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1964, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site- 
packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 748, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", 
line 158, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", 
line 325, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 818, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(packet)
  File "/home/favorite/virtualenv/project/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 763, in _write_bytes
    raise err.OperationalError(
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(104, 
'Connection reset by peer'))")
```

after this error i take this one :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back.  
Please rollback() fully before proceeding (Background on this error at: 
https://sqlalche.me/e/20/8s2b)
20294-ERROR-Error accured
```

i have problem in my cod or this problem is for the server ?